# Uncaught TypeError: currentCoffee.getTotalPrice is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display the total of the getTotalPrice. Im getting the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: currentCoffee.getTotalPrice is not a function.`

```
 function Order ()
 {
     this.coffeeOrder = [];
     // Array of coffees (Start with an empty array)
     this.addCoffee = function(coffee)
     // addCoffee() add a coffee to the array
     {
                 this.coffeeOrder.push(coffee)
     };
     this.getTotalPrice = function()
     // getTotalPrice() is the combined prices of all coffees in the order
     {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.coffeeOrder.length; i++)
            {
                total = total + this.coffeeOrder[i].getTotalPrice()
            }
            return total;
        };      
 }

 var order = new Order();

 function display()
 {
 // Remove the current display
        $("#tablebody tr").remove();

       // Build the html display
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < order.coffeeOrder.length; i++)
        {
            var currentCoffee = order.coffeeOrder[i];
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + currentCoffee.collectionName() + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" +"R"+ currentCoffee.getTotal() + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" +"R"+ currentCoffee.getTotalPrice() + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
        }
            // Append html to dom
            $("#tablebody").append(html);
}
```

**What can I do to fix the problem?
Thanking you in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

`currentCoffee`doesn't have a function `getTotalPrice`.
Seems like you want to use `order.getTotalPrice()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. That don't seam to be the problem

Comment: Is this all the code you have? Maybe make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with all your source code.